# An operations error occurred when using DirectorySearcher

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had this error:

> An operations error occurred

The error occurred here:

```
SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();
```

The full code:

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();

searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
string UserName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
searcher.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                "(sAMAccountName={0})", UserName);

SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();
```

Comment: Sorry buddy, it's hard to trouble shoot w/o more info.  Is there an inner exception?

Comment: Did you set the root of your DirectorySearcher obj?